# No wireless interfaces found

Tags: networking, wifi, raspbian-jessie, raspi-config

I am currently trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 3 to Wifi, but the UI is telling me "No wireless interface found".

Here is my ifconfig :

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.23.218  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        ether b8:27:eb:07:ea:13  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12234  bytes 782479 (764.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11712  bytes 7580720 (7.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 13  bytes 642 (642.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 642 (642.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.115  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        ether b8:27:eb:52:bf:46  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 251  bytes 64870 (63.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 27  bytes 3782 (3.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:c0:ca:95:a4:71  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 326  bytes 98072 (95.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4  bytes 412 (412.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

As you can see, I have two wireless interfaces. The default one on the Raspberry, and another one that I usually use for my computer, but I decided to give it a try.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface lo inet interface
iface eth0 inet static
address 169.254.23.218
netmask 255.255.0.0
gateway 169.254.168.188
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

My static ip adress on eth0 is so that I can connect in SSH directly via ethernet from my laptop, because I have no screen for my RaspberryPi.

I also tried

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

and

```
sudo dhcpcd wlan0
```

but that does not solve the problem.

Do you have any idea that could help me ?

Thanks a lot,
Djaz

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with your `/etc/network/interfaces`

1. You have ignored the warning "# Please note that this file is
   written to be used with dhcpcd # For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'"
2. You are attempting to assign a [Link-local
   address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) to `eth0`
   and even more pointlessly to the gateway.
3. You are not invoking `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (so
   it is a mystery how `wlan0` got an address).
4. There is no `wlan1` section
5. You are calling `dhcp` which will prevent `dhcpcd` running resulting
   in "No wireless interface found".

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for correct settings, although you would be better using the current Raspbian, rather than the obsolete, unsupported `Jessie`.

PS It is unclear what, if anything, the 2nd wireless interface is suposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually setup a wireless connection in /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf, make sure there are no spaces around the equal sign after the **network** keyword. Also make sure of other formatting like **not adding commas after each line**

```
network={

}
```

And not

```
network = {

}
```

All these make access to wpa_supplicant.conf inaccessible by the OS.

You can also run the following to find the exact problem:

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
```

Find more on this post: [WiFi won't start](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/wifi-wont-start)

Answer (score 0):

I use a Raspberry Pi 2 model B with a wireless dongle usb realtek, with the current raspbian version show the error 'No wireless interfaces found'

I solve this problem using a old version for raspbian, can download it from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/raspbian-2019-04-09/