# WiFi Doesn't Connect After Reboot

Tags: wifi, pi-4

I am super new to coding and have been trying my hand at setting up a Magic Mirror with a Raspberry Pi 4B (purchased [here](https://shop.dakboard.com/collections/dakboard-cpu/products/dakboard-cpu-4)). I've been doing pretty well but ran into a problem where my WiFi no longer connects after a reboot. I may not have been searching for the correct keywords, but eventually found a command from [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/wifi-wont-start) that I can run to successfully obtain a connection...BUT I'd really like to know why this works and what I can do to fix the problem overall.

This is the command that *fixes* things:

```
sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -d
```

and this is what my wpa_supplicant.conf file looks like:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
      ssid="MY_NETWORK_SSID"
      psk="MY_WIFI_PASSWORD"
}
```

I have edited/re-set the wpa_supplicant.conf file a few different ways from the command line based on posts I viewed to no avail. I've also re-set the WiFi from the `raspi-config` menu but after rebooting its back to telling me "No Networks Found" from the desktop/GUI.

Please let me know if I am missing any information that could be helpful. I appreciate you taking the time to *hopefully* help me out :)

Comment: Please do not change the title to "solved" but mark the correct answer instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I still don't know why it was happening but I found a way to have the pi execute the command that *fixes* things by adding it to my magic mirror start script. So IF for some reason anyone else has the same issue you can get around it by...

1. Setting up the MM Start Script per [HowTo: Magic Mirror – Setting up the autostart](https://nerdiy.de/en/magicmirror-autostart-einrichten/)
2. and adding the following text:

`cd ~/MagicMirror`

`sudo wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -d`

`DISPLAY=:0 npm start`

I tested it a few times and now my magic mirror autostarts WITH wifi as expected (yay!)

Comment: Once you can (I think its 24 hours), please accept this answer, unless a  better answer comes up, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, my magic is running but dont connect my WIFI. Can you help me?

[image: My conf]

MY LOGS from script: https://pastecode.io/s/w9b2wrgx

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/124767)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to force the pi to connect to the network when booting.

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`, comment all uncommented stuffs and write:

```
...
#source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d //Comment it!
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid  {SSID}
    wpa-psk   {PASSWD}
```

Then, edit `/etc/rc.local` and add the following on top of `exit 0`:

```
...
dhclient wlan0
exit 0 // This indicates the position.
```

This solves the issue.

So, I guess the issue is that after upgrade or something, the configuration files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d` disappeared, so it won't reconnect to the WiFi network.

Hope that helps.

Sincerely.